# Cannot set secret value in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to crete a "secret value" using Azure Key Vault. I am following a tutorial from Microsoft located here ... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/

I was able to create a Key Vault using ...

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName 'MyKeyVaultName' -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroup' -Location 'West US'
```

I can also verify it was created by using ...

`Get-AzureRmKeyVault`

I am able to **create** the secret value by using the following ...

`$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Pa$$w0rd' -AsPlainText -Force`

However when I try to **set** the key ...

`$secret = Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyKeyVaultName' -Name 'SQLPassword' -SecretValue $secretvalue`

I get an error that says

`Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Operation "set" is not allowed`

I thought that I had gained all access to the Key Vault by creating it? Do I need to add specific permissions?

Here is a screen capture of the error from powershell
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Likely a permissions issue.  Try the following:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName ‘{your vault name}’ –UserPrincipalName ‘{your account email}’ –PermissionsToKeys all –PermissionsToSecrets all
```

Comment: Right on point. And if you're as unlucky as I was...
This command will give you an error about guest users not being allowed.
I found this article though:
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/638a0697-29a6-4b13-98d2-9c1558deb6c9/azure-powershell-guest-users-are-not-allowed-to-perform-this-action-for-creating-vaults-adding?forum=AzureKeyVault)
Basically, if you get the guest issue, delete and recreate the user account in azure ad

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that you are not creating a key to attach a secret to, You need to call `Add-AzureKeyVaultKey` to create that key. Like this...

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault    

$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Pa$$w0rd' `
              -AsPlainText -Force  

$key = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName $vault.VaultName `
              -Name Test01 `
              -Destination Software   

(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vault.VaultName `
              -Name test01).SecretValueText
```

which returns

> Pa$$w0rd